# Jquery Repeater with checkbox and radio problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a dynamic form that uses the jquery.repeater plugin.

When a user clicks on a checkbox or radio it retrieves a set of fields for that option and inserts in into a container below the checkbox.

I have a dropdown selection that has the same functionality, and works fine.

When I have several repeater items, and one clicks on a checkbox or radio input it always skips the form and insert in the first repeater item at the top of the form.

here is the code:

```js
$(document).on('change','.optionsCheckbox',function(e){
  var option    = $(this).attr("data-opt");
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    var item = $(this).attr("data-itm");
  }else{
    item     = 0;   
  }
    
  var optionTemplate = $(this).closest(".checkboxContainer").find(".optionTemplate");
  getOptionsCheckbox(item,option,optionTemplate);
    
});
    
getOptionsCheckbox = function(item,option,optionTemplate) {
    
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getOptionCheckbox.php",
    data:{option:option,item:item},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
    
      $(optionTemplate).html(response["htmlArray"]);    
    
    }
    
  });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. Was a issue with the bootstrap custom-control-input and custom-control-label.

Solved using the following:

```
<div class="col-6">

<div class="checkboxContainer">

<div class="form-group">
        
<div class="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input optionsCheckbox" name="checkbox/<?=$frm_opt["options_id"]?>/<?=$frmItm["options_items_id"]?>" id="checkbox/<?=$frm_opt["options_id"]?>/<?=$frmItm["options_items_id"]?>" value="<?=$frmItm["options_items_id"]?>" data-itm="<?=$frmItm["options_items_id"]?>" data-opt="<?=$frmItm["options_id"]?>">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox/<?=$frm_opt["options_id"]?>/<?=$frmItm["options_items_id"]?>"><?=$frmItm["options_items_title"]?></label> 
</div> 

<div class="optionTemplate"></div>  

</div> 

</div>

</div>
```